# How to change configurable product "Add to Cart" button label to something else in the category page

Tags: configurable-product, theme, magento2.3.3

I am building a **custom theme**

I need to change the configurable products "**Add to Cart**" button label to "**See Options**" in **category page**.

Only for the **configurable product**.

Any Help will Appreciate!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change  `Add to Cart` to `See Options` on product category (list page), You need to edit following file:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

on `list.phtml`, You can check product type i.e

```
$_product->getTypeId();//it will give product type simple,configurable
```

Based on product type you can change Add to cart text like:

```
<?php if($_product->getTypeId()=='configurable')  { ?>
<a class="product-button"
   href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('See Options')) ?>
</a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <button type="submit"
            title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
            class="action tocart primary">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
    </button>
<?php } ?>
```

Above code will change text only for configurable product and add a link to product view page.

**Note:** You need to remove original Add to cart button and add code given in solution.

Comment: Your solution works and you are the best, Thank you.

Comment: Welcome, Glad to know :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you find the list file from which the list of product code is there.
So, just need to check in add to cart button with this code.

```
if($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE)    
{    
     echo "product is configurable";
}
```

You just need to put add to cart label code in between the if condition and your work will be done.

Thanks